# Grails 3.0 html table change input by default button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails, partial-page-refresh

I'm working on a project using grails 3. One of the tasks include displaying a table with information and input column like this:

[image]

2 text fields are present and 3 buttons.
button D populates the first textfield
button D1 populates the second textfield
button D2 populates both of them
finally the result will be stored in a single domain class at submit button.

HTML Table is dynamically generated.

No need of database queries or controller call. It can be just rendering value 0 or a random one. I'm not very experienced in jquery and javascript.

**In summary:**

1) Display table with 2 input text fields

2) user can populate them or use default buttons for this(row by row or with master button)

3) Once finished submit button will save the information to the db

Note: by refresh I mean if there is a value in the text field the value to be overrided if the button is pressed.

Sample  : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkqwpc3L/1/)

```
document.getElementById("hour").value = numberHour;
```

How can be achieved that?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? Your description doesn't really describe anything. If you want to _refresh the table_ what do you mean by that? After inputs just clear it? Need more detailed explanation.

Comment: Initially the table will be the same as the screen. The user can put values in the text fields row by row or to use some of the buttons to update those values. When the user finish than he will press submit in order to save information in the database.

Answer (score 0):

For now I'll use the following code until something better is found :

[http://jsfiddle.net/dkqwpc3L/2/](http://Jsfiddle)

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="hour0"></input>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="minute0"></input>

<button onclick="myFunction('hour0')">Click for Hour</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2('minute0')">Click for Minute</button>
<button onclick="myFunction3('0')">Click for Time</button>
<button onclick="myFunction4('0')">Initialise</button>


<input class="form-control" type="text" id="hour1"></input>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="minute1"></input>

<button onclick="myFunction('hour1')">Click for Hour</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2('minute1')">Click for Minute</button>
<button onclick="myFunction3('1')">Click for Time</button>
<button onclick="myFunction4('1')">Initialise</button>

<script>
function myFunction(name)
{
var numberHour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 23) + 1  
document.getElementById(name).value = numberHour;
}
function myFunction2(name)
{
var numberHour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59) + 1  
document.getElementById(name).value = numberHour;
}
function myFunction3(name)
{
var Hour ='hour'+name
var Minute ='minute'+name
var numberHour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 23) + 1  
document.getElementById(Hour).value = numberHour;
var numberHour = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59) + 1  
document.getElementById(Minute).value = numberHour;
}
function myFunction4(name)
{
var Hour ='hour'+name
var Minute ='minute'+name
document.getElementById(Hour).value = '';
document.getElementById(Minute).value = '';
}
</script>
```